# While Loop is running twice in C

Tags: c

I Have written a simple while program in C

```
// Online C compiler to run C online.
// Write C code in this online editor and run it.

#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum
{
    false = 0,
    true = 1
} bool;

int main() {
    bool res = true;
    while (res)
    {
        char choice;
        printf("Success! \n");
        printf("Do you want to continue(y/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
        {
            res = false;
        }
    }
    printf("Good Bye");
}
```

The Program run successfully but when I type Y in Do you want to continue the loop is executed twice. How Can I Solve this?

Comment: Just as an aside, why not use stdbool?

Answer (score 2):

Add a space before `%c` in [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) it skip all whitspaces(newline) like

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
       ^
```

> when I type Y in Do you want to continue the loop is executed twice ?

When you type Y+enter this will go like `"Y\n"` and this new line will taked by next iteration, so use above meathod to discard it.

Similiar Questions :

1)[scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Thanks.

Comment: An excerpt of and/or a link to documentation or support explaining the behavior (even be it another SO answer, which would indicate a likely duplicate) would improve this answer.

Comment: It answers/solves the issue. Imagine this: A programming teacher says use `" %c"` and the teacher is very clear to use a space. The teacher gives an explanation that it skips white space (as this answer does). What resource/course material support the teacher’s claim?

Comment: Links to others resources tend to disappear. ;-)